# Is there an open crowd-based peer-review tool?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I would like to know, if anybody is familiar with any open crowd-based peer-review tools?

If I as a student, for example, use [www.academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/), is it then possible to get my papers peer-reviewed? I understand that this normally happens if I write a conference paper or a phd. But would like to know, if there is any open tool, where I can add papers and get reviews in a not-formal way?

Comment: Whatever you decide, be SURE you understand the potential risks of sharing your research ideas and any findings in an Open forum. Unfortunately, you don't always know who can be trusted with this sort of information. (It's sad, but it's still a reality). As a possible alternative, it's usually an accepted practice to ask a trusted colleague or faculty member to look over your paper and give you their opinions. Of course, you want to be respectful of their time. If you ask them to look over it, just make sure you say something like, "if you have the time, would you be willing to...". If they sa

Comment: Try to clarify what you're looking for. Particularly, what do you mean by "peer"? Why does that not contradict "open"; or, what do you mean by "open"? Do you mean "post a paper, where anyone can make anonymous comments on it"?

Comment: Yes, I have published in academic journals many times. It's a great tool free to use for anyone.

Comment: @user6726 with open I mean something like stackexchange, like a forum where everyone can contribute. And by peer, I mean people of interrest, who could contribute with meaningful feedback, maybe that's not the original meaning of "peer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides http://peerevaluation.org, there is http://www.peerageofscience.org; and there is also reddit.com. Reddit is most like SE in terms of user interaction, however they have some problems with quality control. It is "open" in the sense that anyone can offer material and make a comment (review): it is "not entirely open" in the sense that authors and reviewers have the option of using a pseudonym, so real identities are usually not known. The other two sites are open in the latter sense, that authors and reviewers are openly identified (as far as I can tell), but peerageofscience requires reviewers to "have published a peer reviewed scientific article in an established international journal, as first or corresponding author", so it is closed to reviewers without that credential. (I am not sure about peerevaluation but it does not seem to require any qualifications from reviewers though it does ask you to categorize yourself).

Answer (score 1):

http://peerevaluation.org/ was envisioned as such a forum. I am not sure to which extent it is popular in your comunity and what is the current status of the project.

Comment: That looks interesting, but also like it's not so much in use.

Answer (score 1):

"Crowd-based" is not "peer review". So, while there are platforms Open Peer Review, these still assume that the person doing the reviewing is a "peer" and not someone random from the public. The only mature one I know of is [Science Open](http://about.scienceopen.com/what-is-post-publication-peer-review) which does both publishing and peer-review.